# Extract data from XML document using t-sql

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2019

I have been trying to extract data from the following xml doc using t-sql on sql server 2019.

### XML:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.URL1.com/1</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://www.URL1.com/11</image:loc>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://www.URL1.com/12</image:loc>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://www.URL1.com/13</image:loc>
    </image:image>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.URL1.com/2</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://www.URL1.com/21</image:loc>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://www.URL1.com/22</image:loc>
    </image:image>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>https://www.URL1.com/3</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>https://www.URL1.com/32</image:loc>
    </image:image>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

I would like to extract data out of the xml document into a SQL Server table. My desired output as below

### Desired output:

```
+------------------------+-------------------------+
|          Loc           |        ImageLoc         |
+------------------------+-------------------------+
| https://www.URL1.com/1 | https://www.URL1.com/11 |
| https://www.URL1.com/1 | https://www.URL1.com/12 |
| https://www.URL1.com/1 | https://www.URL1.com/13 |
| https://www.URL1.com/2 | https://www.URL1.com/21 |
| https://www.URL1.com/2 | https://www.URL1.com/22 |
| https://www.URL1.com/3 | https://www.URL1.com/32 |
+------------------------+-------------------------+
```

My Attempts have been failed so far miserably. I have tried many thing but the only thing that allowed me to get even the Loc element was the following, I have tried using OUTER APPLY/CROSS APPLY to het the ImageLoc with no luck.

### My Attempt:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SELECT @xml = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'M:\Files\MyXML.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x

SELECT
    t.c.value('(text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') URLs
,   t2.i.value('(text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') URLs

FROM @xml.nodes('*:urlset/*:url/*:loc') t(c)
OUTER APPLY  @xml.nodes('*:urlset/*:url/*:loc/*:image/*:loc') t2(i)
```

Could you please help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer was posted by [lptr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12403612/lptr) in the comments as just a link to a fiddle. As the OP has said that it answers their question, and lptr doesn't wish/respond to  posting answers, I have migrated it to the answer section.

Here they use the `*` wildcard rather than defining the namespace to get the values from the XML:

> [dbfiddle.uk/...](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a756d3c64db927c8ed3af3369d58bf6f)
>
> ```sql
> SELECT
>     t.c.value('(*:loc/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') URLs
> ,   t2.i.value('(text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(max)') URLs
>
> FROM @xml.nodes('*:urlset/*:url') t(c)
> OUTER APPLY  t.c.nodes('*:image/*:loc') t2(i);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your namespace in your SQL as well. This can be done with putting `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` at the start your query and defining it there. Then you can define the `image` namespace and prefix it in your references and return the values from the nodes:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('xyz' AS image)
SELECT u.i.value('(../loc/text())[1]','varchar(500)') AS loc,
       u.i.value('(image:loc/text())[1]','varchar(500)') AS loc
FROM @xml.nodes('urlset/url/image:image') u(i);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=db63e61c191432db5f10fbecb4bb0d41)